# Communication between Google Glass and smartphone (SHARE JSON DATA)

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk, android-sharing

I need process some information in my device (sensorial information) and share some of this information to the glass. The glass only have to display information. what is the best way to do this?? I have read about sharing data through bluetooth, through the cloud and use the API of the GDK but i dont know if these are the best ways to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: You may get more responses posting on the Google Glass developer community, see https://plus.google.com/communities/105104639432156353586

Answer (score 1):

Using Firebase might be of interest. It enables real-time access to data from multiple devices. Here is a blog of an example set-up using an Arduino: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-09-22-realtime-iot-dev-with-firebase.html I've seen a similar set-up where results are passed to a tablet and Glass.

Comment: Thanks, its a ussefull link. Im goint to see it and and I'll tell you.